# Django filter LIKE Query in array ORM (icontains)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

**Views.py**

```
print(keywords_array)      #['Donut', 'Pizza']
print(moods_array)         #['Dating', 'Family']

items=ItemVariation.objects.filter(item__restaurant__id = i['restaurant']['id'],keyword__name__icontains=keywords_array,keyword__mood__moods__in=moods_array).select_related()
```

I need to filter **keyword__name__icontains** but variable is an array ['Donut', 'Pizza'] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case it is probably better to construct a regex, and use the [**`__iregex`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex):

```
import re

data = ['Donut', 'Pizza']
the_regex = '|'.join(re.escape(datum) for datum in data)

items=ItemVariation.objects.filter(
    item__restaurant__id = i['restaurant']['id'],
    keyword__name__iregex=the_regex,
    keyword__mood__moods__in=moods_array
).select_related()
```

An alternative is to create an long OR, and each time use `keyword__name__icontains` per item in the array. But this will probably be more "ugly".

Comment: it is returning  
WHERE 
  (
    "backend_item"."restaurant_id" = 1 
    AND "backend_mood"."moods" IN (Family, Dating) 
    AND UPPER("backend_keyword"."name" :: text) LIKE UPPER(% [ 'Donut', 'Pizza' ] %)
  )

Comment: @tarunsharma: did you wrote the construction of `the_regex`? It looks as if you only passed the data to the `__iregex` lookup...

Comment: the_regex = '|'.join(re.escape(datum) for datum in keywords_array)
                items=ItemVariation.objects.filter(item__restaurant__id = i['restaurant']['id'],keyword__name__iregex=the_regex,keyword__mood__moods__in=moods_array).select_related()

Comment: It should look like: `WHERE ... keyword.name REGEXP Donut|Pizza` (tested it locally. So it looks like you did something wrong, or the query originates from somewhere else.

Comment: O thanks, I missed to import re it is working Thanks for this unique answer